# WPF - How to change text and image color in ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make a menu from a ListBox
How can I change the text and image color when an item is selected?

Example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VE1o.png)

I got it like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n4aW.jpg)

Code XAML:

```
<ListView Background="Transparent"
                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="0 0 0 0">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Border Name="_Border" Margin="3 0 3 0" Padding="5 5 5 5"
                                            CornerRadius="3"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                            Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="#36A3F6"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListViewItem IsSelected="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Images/home.png" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="5 0 5 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="item1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Images/home.png" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="5 0 5 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="item2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Images/home.png" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="5 0 5 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="item3"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the Text color you could simply put another Setter into your "IsSelected"-Trigger like:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
```

Changing the color of the .png-Image wont be that simple though.
You should consider converting your Icons (like the home.png) into Paths, so you can transform them easier and change their color ("Fill"-Property)

If you want to go further with your project, also consider putting your styles into seperate ResourceDictionaries to clean up your code